# Why does my for loop remove duplicate letters

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to make a hangman game but the code removes duplicates so instead of clammer it would output clamer

here's my code:

```py
import json
import random
#variables and classes
class currentlives:
    onelt = f"    _____ \n   | \n   | \n   | \n   | \n   | \n   | \n   | \n   | \n___|___"
    twolt = f"    _____ \n   |   ___ \n   |  /   \ \n   |  \___/ \n   | \n   | \n   | \n   | \n   | \n___|___"
    thrlt = f"    _____ \n   |   ___ \n   |  /   \ \n   |  \___/ \n   |    | \n   |    -    \n   |    | \n   |    | \n   |  \n___|___"
    foult = f"    _____ \n   |   ___ \n   |  /   \ \n   |  \___/ \n   |    | \n   | ------- \n   |    | \n   |    | \n   |       \n___|___"
    fivlt = f"    _____ \n   |   ___ \n   |  /   \ \n   |  \___/ \n   |    | \n   | ------- \n   |    | \n   |    | \n   |   /   \n___|___"
    sixlt = f"    _____ \n   |   ___ \n   |  /   \ \n   |  \___/ \n   |    | \n   | ------- \n   |    | \n   |    | \n   |   / \ \n___|___ (LAST LIFE)"
lives_counter = 0
Vals = {}
letters_used = []

#defining function zone:
def Turn():
    global lives_counter
    global Guesses
    while lives_counter <= 4:
        
        if lives_counter == 0:
            print(currentlives.onelt, f"you have used: {letters_used}, and the current letters look like {Guesses}, now which letter would you like to guess next?")
            pguess = input()
            check(pguess)
            if Win() == 10:
                print("Congrats you won!")
                break
            Turn()
        elif lives_counter == 1:
            print(currentlives.twolt, f"you have used: {letters_used}, and the current letters look like {Guesses}, now which letter would you like to guess next?")
            pguess = input()
            check(pguess)
            if Win() == 10:
                print("Congrats you won!")
                break
            Turn()
        elif lives_counter == 2:
            print(currentlives.thrlt, f"you have used: {letters_used}, and the current letters look like {Guesses}, now which letter would you like to guess next?")
            pguess = input()
            check(pguess)
            if Win() == 10:
                print("Congrats you won!")
                break
            Turn()
        elif lives_counter == 3:
            print(currentlives.foult, f"you have used: {letters_used}, and the current letters look like {Guesses}, now which letter would you like to guess next?")
            pguess = input()
            check(pguess)
            if Win() == 10:
                print("Congrats you won!")
                break
            Turn()
        elif lives_counter == 4:
            print(currentlives.fivlt, f"you have used: {letters_used}, and the current letters look like {Guesses}, now which letter would you like to guess next?")
            pguess = input()
            check(pguess)
            if Win() == 10:
                print("Congrats you won!")
                break
            Turn()
        elif lives_counter == 5:
            print(currentlives.sixlt, f"you have used: {letters_used}, and the current letters look like {Guesses}, now which letter would you like to guess next?")
            pguess = input()
            check(pguess)
            if Win() == 10:
                print("Congrats you won!")
                break
            Turn()
        else:
            print(Vals)
    else:
        print(f"GAME OVER, sorry that might've been impossible but you ran out of lives, please play again but here's the answer {WChoice}")
        
def TurnDebug():
    global Vals
    print(Vals)

def check(guess):
    global Guesses
    global lives_counter
    if guess in Vals:
        Vals[guess] = guess
        Guesses = list(Vals.values())
    else:
        letters_used.append(guess)
        lives_counter += 1

def Win():
    x = 0
    winvar = 10
    for value in Vals:
        if value == Vals[value]:
            x += 1
            if x == len(WChoice):
                return winvar
#word picker + stuff:
def Word_picker():
    global Rword
    global Words
    global Dictonaryftg
    with open(r"C:\Users\Larry\Downloads\EnglishDictionary.json", 'r') as f:
        Dictonaryftg = json.load(f)
    Words = list(Dictonaryftg.keys())
    Rword = str(random.choice(Words))
    return Rword



WChoice = str(Word_picker())
for letter in WChoice:
    Vals[letter] = "_"
Guesses = list(Vals.values())
Turn()
```

note the json file has 37,000+ words
note the issue is in either the wordpicker but when i used turndebbug() it made me realized the issue was probably in the for loop

ignore my bad code in turn i know how to fix it but i want to know my issue before trying to reduce my code

Comment: One alternative option is to use a list for `Vals` rather than a dictionary

Comment: I have so many questions about your code. Why bother using a class if you're just using it to store a few strings? Everything else is a global variable anyway, why aren't those in the class? Why use a while loop if you're just going to repeat the same block of code 6 times? The values of your dictionaries carry basically no information (besides what's already conveyed in the key), so why are you using dictionaries instead of lists or sets? Do you know what a boolean variable is? If so, then why does your `Win` function return either `None` or `10`?

Answer (score 1):

```
WChoice = str(Word_picker())
for letter in WChoice:
    Vals[letter] = "_"
```

You're using a dictionary.  Dictionary keys are unique.